# How can I deal with linked comboBoxes (when I change the value of one it changes it to other as well)?

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I am using several comboBoxes in my app and I am struggling with the following problem.

[image]

And when I change the value of any of the boxes it changes it on others too.

[image]

Just to get you guys in the flow of the app I am gonna explain whats going on. The "Primary Muscle" box has a crucial role. If I select "Chest" there it will change the DataSource of the four boxes below with only "chest exercise". The real problem is that when I select "Bench Press" for example on the first "Primary Exercise" it will change it for all of them below that one, like its showed on the screenshots.

```
    private void metroComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)primaryMuscleBox.SelectedItem == "Chest")
        {
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox1, chestExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox2, chestExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox3, chestExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox4, chestExercies);

        }
        else if ((string)primaryMuscleBox.SelectedItem == "Back")
        {
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox1, backExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox2, backExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox3, backExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox4, backExercies);
        }
        else if ((string)primaryMuscleBox.SelectedItem == "Legs")
        {
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox1, legsExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox2, legsExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox3, legsExercies);
            AddItems(primaryExerciesBox4, legsExercies);
        }
    }

    private void AddItems(MetroComboBox comboBox, List<string> name)
    {
        comboBox.DataSource = null;
        comboBox.DataSource = name;
    }
```

I forgot to mention that I am not using the standard comboBox, I am using the "metroComboBox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because all your `ComboBox`*es* are bound to same data source.
You have to set new `BindingSource` to each combo boxes:

```
private void AddItems(MetroComboBox comboBox, List<string> name)
{
    comboBox.DataSource =  new BindingSource(name, "");
}
```

Or you can use `ToList()` to create new `List`

```
private void AddItems(MetroComboBox comboBox, List<string> name)
{
    comboBox.DataSource =  name.ToList();
}
```